# Appsync: Get user info in context.identity when using auth0

Tags: auth0, aws-appsync

In `Appsync`, when using `cognito userpools` with `auth0` as your identity provider, the identity is as follows:

```
 "identity": {
        "claims": {
            "sub": "2e4dd05d-12e8-4c3e-af37-a23198d4bdfa",
            "cognito:groups": [
                "ap-southeast-1_afHwI1Nss_auth0app"
            ],
            "token_use": "access",
            "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin openid profile email",
            "auth_time": 1573038746,
            "iss": "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-1_afHwI1Nss",
            "exp": 1573042346,
            "iat": 1573038746,
            "version": 2,
            "jti": "0481d844-3d59-4406-b9c2-83799ef6c1ff",
            "client_id": "<lots of numbers>",
            "username": "auth0app_auth0|5d9c81872fce3b0ded382498"
        },
        "defaultAuthStrategy": "ALLOW",
        "groups": [
            "ap-southeast-1_afHwI1Nss_auth0app"
        ],
        "issuer": "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-1_afHwI1Nss",
        "sourceIp": [
            "<>"
        ],
        "sub": "2e4dd05d-12e8-4c3e-af37-a23198d4bdfa",
        "username": "auth0app_auth0|5d9c81872fce3b0ded382498"
    },
```

This username is not at all useful when displayed on the client. However in `cognito`, when I check the attributes for that user, there are extra attributes I have mapped in the configs.

```
Groups  ap-southeast-1_afHwI1Nss_auth0app 
Account Status  Enabled / EXTERNAL_PROVIDER
SMS MFA Status  Disabled
Last Modified   Nov 6, 2019 11:12:24 AM
Created Oct 25, 2019 8:41:01 AM
sub 2e4dd05d-12e8-4c3e-af37-a23198d4bdfa
identities  [{"userId":"auth0|5d9c81872fce3b0ded382498","providerName":"auth0app","providerType":"OIDC","issuer":null,"primary":true,"dateCreated":1571992861820}]
name    skillet
given_name  skillet
email   skillet@nope.com
picture <long-url>
```

Knowing that I am using aws amplify on the client with the `withAuthenticator` HOC, how can I either access these properties from within the appsync resolver context object or have a more friendly username in the identity object?

Answer (score 0):

AppSync has support for OIDC authentication natively. This should allow you to bypass Cognito and allow access the Auth0 token directly. I have not personally tried it with Auth0 but these [Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oidc/openid-connect-discovery) and these [AppSync docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#openid-connect-authorization) are a good place to start.

Comment: I've tried both the tutorial in appsync and auth0 on how to integrate with auth0. It turns out to be authorising with aws via STS and not what you would expect. I had to end up following a tutorial about integrating Azure with appsync to get auth0 working correctly, but you do not ever bypass cognito. One way or another a user is created on cognito for you. I can access the auth0 token directly in my code, but what happens is that the username is then formed by concatenating the auth provider with the userId from the auth provider. Imagine displaying that to the client!